# Specific SQL query with Join and NULL values possible

Tags: sql, postgresql, join

Here is the problem,

I have 2 tables I want to work with,

Table1 :

```
t1_id | t1_name | t1_reference | t1_related | t1_comment

t1_id is a serial
t1_name is a text field
t1_reference is an integer
t1_related is a foreign key pointing to t2_id, is NOT REQUIRED (default NULL)
t1_comment is a text field
```

Table 2 :

```
t2_id | t2_name

t2_id is a serial
t2_name is a text field
```

What I'd like to do is to retrieve ALL t1 fields AND t2_name field when existing, where t1_reference = someValue

I'm really confused about the joins in the queries, and I do not understand how it goes with possible non-existing values in fields... to me, the query should look like :

```
SELECT t1.*,t2_name FROM t1 [... ??? join part ??? ...] WHERE t1_reference = value
```

Actually working on PostgreSQL.

Thanks for reading/help

Comment: This is great practice. Add some data to your tables, try INNER JOIN and LEFT JOIN, with conditions either in WHERE clause or ON clause, and see what changes! Have fun!!!

Comment: Using a `LEFT JOIN` you will be able to get every entry regardless of wether they match a table 2 entry.

Answer (score 1):

You can get the required result by following logic(syntax may be different):

```
SELECT t1.*,t2.t2_name FROM t1, t2 WHERE t1.t1_related=t2.t2_id and t1_reference = ~value~
```

Comment: @Julo0sS if you got the required result please accept my answer.